# How can I plot a mesh-grid like image using pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I have the following lists that I want to plot:

```
x-axis list, y-axis list, point list
```

I would like to plot something like this but not as granular (this example has around 2000 points while I only have 19), how can I create something like this? I have (x point, y point, loss).

[image]

I have tried doing the following:

plt.imshow(loss, extent = [ x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2], aspect="auto", interpolation="nearest", vmax=10)

but I get :

[image]

which I don't think is the right output...

Comment: Did you look at `plt.pcolormesh`?

Comment: @JohanC that's very close to what I want, just not sure how to get it to work? plt.pcolormesh([x-lilst, y-list, points], args)? I'm very new to pyplot so I don't really understand how the plotting generally works.

Comment: Probably, `plt.pcolormesh(x_points, y_points, lost, shading='gouraud')`.   Your `plt.imshow(....)` should also work, but better leave out the `vmax=10`. Your plot suggests most values in `lost` are smaller  than `1`. So maybe setting `vmax=1`, or leave it out to let matplotlib calculate the maximum. Without knowing how your data looks like, guessing is hard.

Comment: Probably, `plt.pcolormesh(x_points, y_points, lost, shading='gouraud')`.   Your `plt.imshow(....)` should also work, but better leave out the `vmax=10`. Your plot suggests most values in `lost` are smaller  than `1`. So maybe setting `vmax=1`, or leave it out to let matplotlib calculate the maximum. Without knowing how your data looks like, guessing is hard.